# How to not match double spaces?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-4.0

So far so good, but I would like to match `"Health and Beauty"`
 instead of `"Health and Beauty _ _ _"` (trailing six spaces)

```
var a = Regex.Match("Health and Beauty      08/05/11 TO 08/11/11",
    @"^(?<dept>.*)" +
    @"(?<startdate>[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})\s+TO\s+" +
    @"(?<enddate>[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})$").Dump();
```

I tried a negative look ahead, but .* continued to match everything.

```
@"^(?<dept>.*(?!(\s\s)))\s+"  // should be "not followed by two spaces
```

I only have the option to match and extract, not to replace (the C# is for an example.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `@"^(?<dept>.*)"` to be non-greedy, and match on extra whitespace after:

```
@"^(?<dept>.*?)\s*"
```